# Iterating through two POST arrays of different length to find customers who bought x,y,z but didn't buy x,y,x,z

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, post, nested-loops

All the answers out there deal with iterating two or more arrays of the same length, or with the same keys, but not here. I tried all of the ideas out there to no avail.

I have two multiple selects submitted in the same POST form - products bought and products not bought. They contain the same products, but as multi selects will rarely have produce the same items in array (think of how many combinations there are.) The first `foreach` works fine and pulls from MySQL all customers who had any of the selected "bought" items. However the second nested `foreach` doesn't iterate - it just takes the first value from the "hasn't brought" array.

HTML part:

```
Find customers who have bought:

<form method="post" action="">
<select name="bought[]" size="5" multiple="multiple">
<option value="RD"> Brown T Shirt </option>
<option value="RDX"> Red T Shirt </option>
<option value="HD"> White T Shirt </option>
<option value="CB"> Black T Shirt</option>
<option value="DA"> Green T Shirt </option>
</select>

But who haven't bought:

<select name="notbought[]" size="5" multiple="multiple">
<option value="RD"> Brown T Shirt </option>
<option value="RDX"> Red T Shirt </option>
<option value="HD"> White T Shirt </option>
<option value="CB"> Black T Shirt</option>
<option value="DA"> Green T Shirt </option>
</select>

<div class="buttons>
<button class="large" type="submit">Get the CSV!</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Then the PHP:

```
<?php
foreach($_POST['bought'] as $bought) {
foreach($_POST['notbought'] as $notbought){

$selectsubs = mysqli_query("SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Territory
                FROM Customers
                WHERE Customer_Type = 'Active'
                AND Products_Bought LIKE '%$bought%'
                AND Products_Bought NOT LIKE '%$notbought%'
                ");


 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectsubs))  {

$csvWriter->addRow();
$csvWriter->addCol($row['Email']);
$csvWriter->addCol($row['First_Name']);
$csvWriter->addCol($row['Last_Name']);
$csvWriter->addCol($row['Territory']);
    }
  }
}
$csvWriter->writeFile("customers.csv");
?>
```

Comment: What does $_POST['notbought'] contain after you submit the form? As in what does it actually pass, var_Dump($_POST['notbought'])

Comment: What do the values of $brought and $notbrought actually contain? If you print your $selectsubs query before passing to the database does it look like a valid query?

Comment: Also what is an example row of the table Customers? From your query it looks like you are storing a list in a single text field? This isn't great Database practise. Maybe consider adding another table called Sales where you have customer id, product id and maybe date, quantity, price paid etc from data mining purposes? Then you could look at using a JOIN, a GROUP BY and then a HAVING clause similar to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708847/using-and-operator-with-subquery/21708940#21708940

Comment: @ Dieter - $_POST['notbought'] contains all of the POSTed options, but they aren't iterated in the SQL query. Only the first option is. @ Acyclic Tau - I'm working with a legacy, imported Access db where data is not in an ideal format and it's not feasible to reorganise it in a better way.

Comment: I wonder if it would be better if the bought/not-bought loops are not nested. If you are settings a number of conditions in each (match in the first, not match in the second) then you can loop through those separately to generate the necessary SQL, and then join it together in one query afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Making the assumption that the Products_Bought field is a comma separated list of products I would be tempted to do this in a single piece of SQL, something like this (not tested):-

```
foreach($_POST['bought'] AS $key=>$value) $_POST['bought'][$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['bought'][$key]);
foreach($_POST['notbought'] AS $key=>$value) $_POST['notbought'][$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['notbought'][$key]);

$bought = 'FIND_IN_SET("'.implode('", REPLACE(Products_Bought, "-", ",")) AND FIND_IN_SET("', $_POST['bought']).'", REPLACE(Products_Bought, "-", ","))';
$notbought = '!FIND_IN_SET("'.implode('", REPLACE(Products_Bought, "-", ",")) AND !FIND_IN_SET("', $_POST['notbought']).'", REPLACE(Products_Bought, "-", ","))';

$selectsubs = mysqli_query("SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Territory
            FROM Customers
            WHERE Customer_Type = 'Active'
            AND $bought
            AND $notbought");
```

This should build up a piece of SQL something like the following:-

```
SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Territory
FROM Customers
WHERE Customer_Type = 'Active'
AND FIND_IN_SET("RD", REPLACE(Products_Bought, '-', ','))
AND FIND_IN_SET("RDX", REPLACE(Products_Bought, '-', ','))
AND !FIND_IN_SET("HD", REPLACE(Products_Bought, '-', ','))
AND !FIND_IN_SET("CB", REPLACE(Products_Bought, '-', ','))
```

However it would probably be better to split the items bought off into another table, with one row per customer / item rather than using a delimited list.

Comment: Isn't this the best way to open a possibility for an sql injection attack?

Comment: Fair comment (I just did a quick answer to demonstrate the solution, and I should have been a bit more explicit), and have updated the code to escape out that possibility

Comment: injection isn't a concern as this is backend only function. @ Kickstart your solution looks interesting but my SQL coding isn't strong enough to fully grasp it. I suppose what you're getting at is to make SQL do the sorting/filtering rather than PHP. Makes sense at least on paper. I'd appreciate if you could elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: It is using FIND_IN_SET to check if a product is in the list (assuming comma separated). This avoids a potential issue with your original script (if someone had bought product RD then it would also find RDX). It is doing one FIND_IN_SET for each product bought, and one for each product not bought. For products bought it is checking a record is found and for products not bought it is checking a record is not found.

Comment: OK thanks. The column is actually hyphen separated, so RD-RDX-CB etc. Also I don't fully grasp your use of the foreach loops - you don't seem to use curly brackets to actually employ them on the query? Only to define the real_escape_string? But thanks for all your help anyway, I'm sure I'll figure it out.

Comment: I have modded the answer to convert from comma separated to hyphen separated. The foreach loops are just there to escape the input data (hence as only one statement is being looped around there is no need to use curly brackets). The SQL is executed once and should give you all the results at once (no need to loop around executing the SQL multiple times).

Comment: thanks for the edit Kickstart, but just to let you know there's something wrong with the syntax within both those $bought and $notbought definitions:

$bought = 'FIND_IN_SET("'.implode('", REPLACE(Products_Bought, '-', ',')) AND FIND_IN_SET("', $_POST['bought']).'", REPLACE(Products_Bought, '-', ','))';
$notbought = '!FIND_IN_SET("'.implode('", REPLACE(Products_Bought, '-', ',')) AND !FIND_IN_SET("', $_POST['notbought']).'", REPLACE(Products_Bought, '-', ','))';

 - both are passed as invalid and the script crashes.

Comment: got it, was just a matter of swapping some single and double quotes. thanks for all your help kickstart, really very appreciated!

Comment: @user3174541: you can (and should) use backticks when adding code to comments, but in general, if you have a lot of code, it may be worth using a pasteboard. As you can see, it isn't very readable!